# what can be the possible length of mask in networking

Tags: networking

What can be the possible length of mask for IPv4 address like I have a IP address `10.16.16.30/24`. Here the length of mask is 24.
I know the theoretical maximum  value is `/32` and minimum `/1`.
Then what will be the maximum and minimum possible practical(used in Network) value for mask.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen /32 routes (host routes) commonly used, and /0 routes (default routes) commonly used, so the practical maxima and minima are the same as the theoretical maxima and minima, i.e. /32 and /0.